# Szego's Limit Theorem for Non-Hermitian Toeplitz Matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, toeplitz-matrices

Toeplitz matrices $A_{n}(f)$ is defined as:

$A_{n}(f)_{i,j}=c_{i-j}$ $0\leq i,j \leq n-1$, where $c_{k}$ are Fourier Coefficients of $f(\theta)=\sum_{k=- 
             \infty}^{+\infty}c_{k}e^{\iota k \theta }$

$n$ here is the order of matrix $A_{n}(f)$.

[Szegos Limit Theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szeg%C5%91_limit_theorems) talk about determinants of large Toeplitz matrices. I am here concerned with the first Szegos limit theorem which states that:
\begin{equation}
lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{Det(A_{n}(f))}{Det(A_{n-1}(f))}=exp\{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}log(f(\theta))d \theta\}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
The Wikipedia article discusses this theorem for $f$ being a non-negative valued function. I am looking for a generalisation of this theorem for $f$ being a complex-valued function. I tried searching the web but could not find a good reference. I am looking for a good reference for Szego's Limit theorems for these complex-valued $f$.

Thank you